# Deleting all the noun phrases from text using Textblob

Tags: python, textblob

I need to delete all the proper noun from the text. 
result is the Dataframe.
I'm using text blob. Below is the code.

```
from textblob import TextBlob

          strings = []
            for col in result:
                for i in range(result.shape[0]):
                    text = result[col][i]
                    Txtblob = TextBlob(text)

                    for word, pos in Txtblob.noun_phrases:
                        print (word, pos)
                        if tag != 'NNP'
                           print(' '.join(edited_sentence))
```

It just recognizes one NNP

Comment: Please check the formatting of your code snippet. You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you share code, with example input and output. That will make it easier to repoduce

Comment: @Philip Please don't encourage people to share their **entire** code, just the minimum required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is the entire code regarding text blob

Comment: Then provide a sample of your input `text` as well as where you set `tag`as and `edited_sentence`. I'm not sure you are aware, but you are missing a `:` after this section `if tag != 'NNP'`, it should be `if tag != 'NNP':`

Comment: @AnnaSmith, did the answer give you the information that you were looking for? If so please mark it as correct so that others can benefit from it, or provide more information so that we may help you.

Comment: @Philip No It did not solve my prob

Comment: @AnnaSmith, could you provide an example `text`input as well as the expected output? Then it would be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @AnnaSmith - are you still interested in the answer? If so could you provide an example of the text where you want to remove noun phrases from, as well as the phrases you expect to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all words tagged with 'NNP' from the following text (from the [documenation](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/index.html)), you can do the following:

```
from textblob import TextBlob

# Sample text
text = '''
The titular threat of The Blob has always struck me as the ultimate movie
monster: an insatiably hungry, amoeba-like mass able to penetrate
virtually any safeguard, capable of--as a doomed doctor chillingly
describes it--"assimilating flesh on contact.'''

text = TextBlob(text)

# Create a list of words that are tagged with 'NNP'
# In this case it will only be 'Blob'
words_to_remove = [word[0] for word in [tag for tag in text.tags if tag[1] == 'NNP']]

# Remove the Words from the sentence, using words_to_remove
edited_sentence = ' '.join([word for word in text.split(' ') if word not in words_to_remove])

# Show the result
print(edited_sentence)
```

out

```
# Notice the lack of the word 'Blob'
'\nThe titular threat of The has always struck me as the ultimate
 movie\nmonster: an insatiably hungry, amoeba-like mass able to 
 penetrate\nvirtually any safeguard, capable of--as a doomed doctor 
 chillingly\ndescribes it--"assimilating flesh on contact.\nSnide 
 comparisons to gelatin be damned, it\'s a concept with the 
 most\ndevastating of potential consequences, not unlike the grey goo 
 scenario\nproposed by technological theorists fearful of\nartificial 
 intelligence run rampant.\n'
```

### Comments for your sample

```
from textblob import TextBlob

strings = [] # This variable is not used anywhere
for col in result:
    for i in range(result.shape[0]):
        text = result[col][i]
        txt_blob = TextBlob(text)

        # txt_blob.noun_phrases will return a list of noun_phrases,
        # To get the position of each list you need use the function 'enuermate', like this
        for word, pos in enumerate(txt_blob.noun_phrases):

            # Now you can print the word and position
            print (word, pos)
            # This will give you something like the following:
            # 0 titular threat
            # 1 blob
            # 2 ultimate movie monster

            # This following line does not make any sense, because tag has not yet been assigned
            # and you are not iterating over the words from the previous step
            if tag != 'NNP'
                # You are not assigning anything to edited_sentence, so this would not work either.
                print(' '.join(edited_sentence))
```

### Your sample with new code

```
from textblob import TextBlob

for col in result:
    for i in range(result.shape[0]):
        text = result[col][i]
        txt_blob = TextBlob(text)

        # Create a list of words that are tagged with 'NNP'
        # In this case it will only be 'Blob'
        words_to_remove = [word[0] for word in [tag for tag in txt_blob.tags if tag[1] == 'NNP']]

        # Remove the Words from the sentence, using words_to_remove
        edited_sentence = ' '.join([word for word in text.split(' ') if word not in words_to_remove])

        # Show the result
        print(edited_sentence)
```

Comment: @AnnaSmith, I've updated the answer. I've also tested that this works, on the provided sample, which removes the only word tagged `NNP` (`Blob`). Let me know if you have problems getting it working.